# An elementary question about grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, notation

Recently, I am studying grammar in automata. And, I have few information about this subject.

I have a  grammar with rules $\{S\to ASA, A\to aA, A\to \epsilon\}$.

Is it true if I say that $S\to aASA$ by rules $S\to ASA, A\to aA$?

Comment: Please, update your question specifying:
1. what is confusing you,
2. what have you tried,
3. that grammar is not regular, perhaps, remove the `regular-languages` label.

Comment: Although the generated language is regular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but not precise.

Usually one distinguishes between the arrow notation for the rules $A \to aA$ and the notation for derivation in the grammar, that is the application of the rules in strings $ASA\Rightarrow aASA$.

In your example two consecutive rules are applied, and we write $S\Rightarrow ASA \Rightarrow aASA$, or combining steps $S\Rightarrow^* aASA$.

Observe that your grammar will generate the empty language. There are no productions that remove the initial variable $S$.